# How to check if the request URI have got any parameters

Tags: c#, .net, query-string

I have my class on C# on .NET, called after a request by an URI. I need to check if this URI contains some parameters or not.

For example :

```
http://www.website.com/page.aspx?ID=9           // must return YES
http://www.website.com/page.aspx?ID=9&Page=2    // must return YES
http://www.website.com/page.aspx                // must return NO
```

is it possible? Of course I couldn't know the name for each parameters in the URI, so for a random querystring like :

```
http://www.website.com/page.aspx?RandomParameter=1
```

I need to return YES. Can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to allow for `Request.QueryString` being `null` as well (no parameters).

to return a `string`:

```
return Request.QueryString != null && Request.QueryString.Count > 0 ? "YES" : "NO";
```

to return a `bool`:

```
return Request.QueryString != null && Request.QueryString.Count > 0;
```

Answer (score 6):

It has been quite a while since I have worked with these, but I believe something like the following should fit your needs:

**Solution:**

```
if(Request.QueryString != null && Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
{
     return "YES";
}
else
{
     return "NO";
}
```

**Inline Solution (If this was all you needed to do):**

```
return (Request.QueryString != null && Request.QueryString.Count > 0) ? "YES":"NO";
```

You can find more information on Request.QueryString [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: But Request.QueryString== null means that querystring doesnt contain parameters?

Comment: Fixed Sorry :) This will just check if any parameters exist and will output "YES", otherwise "NO". Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Rionmonster `Request.QueryString == null` would throw an exception in your code examples. See my answer above.

Comment: @Chris - I initially had that in there. As I mentioned, I wasn't sure if it was necessary

Comment: @Rionmonster, it is necessary as `Request.QueryString` can be `null`. Your update for inline solution is still wrong: `Request.QueryString.Count>0 && Request.QueryString != null` needs to check for `null` first like `Request.QueryString != null && Request.QueryString.Count>0`

Comment: I appreciate it Chris - like I said, been out of doing it for awhile. (And it's the last day before a vacation so... :) +1 for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this method, If the requested page has any querystirng parameters defined then it will return true, otherwise it will return false

```
if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys())
{
    Response.Write("The requested page URI has parameters");
}
```